# What do you call in English for the words like this 'rotor'?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

Consider the word **rotor**. Whichever way you read it, from left to right or from right to left, you get the same word.

Is there any specific word for words like this?

Comment: A little tip! You may first check ['Reverso'](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml) dictionary that gives you a word depending on the description. Test it: Search: word that reads the same reverse and see the *magic*! :)

Comment: @User1 Different people use different conventions to signify a linguistic structure... I've seen all-caps used by many newbies around ELL that don't know the English-language conventions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is called a *[palindrome](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palindrome)*:

> a word, verse, or sentence (as “Able was I ere I saw Elba”) or a number (as 1881) that reads the same backward or forward

Example:

> Madam
>   Bob
>   Otto

As it is clear from the meaning that it is not only limited to words, but phrases, sentences and numbers, too. Allowances may be made for adjustments to capital letters, punctuation, and word dividers.

Example:

> - Nurses run.
> - A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!
> - A Santa lived as a devil at NASA.
> - 12321

---

There is another word, *semordnilap*, which is nothing but *palindromes* spelled backward.
However, *semordnilap* is a name coined for words that spell a different word in reverse.

Example:

> stressed <=> desserts

---

Sources:

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) and 
[Merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palindrome)

Comment: One of my favorite palindromes of all is the _Crab Canon_, found in the book Gödel Escher Bach, by Hofstadter. Is essentially a [palindromic conversation](http://www.3quarksdaily.com/3quarksdaily/2011/06/a-crab-canon-for-douglas-hofstadter.html), and worth a mention just for its sheer genius.

Comment: There is also this [Weird Al spoof on a Bob Dylan song](https://vimeo.com/44024588) filled with [palindromes](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/weirdalyankovic/bob.html).

Comment: "the word X is nothing but Y spelt backwards. however, it is also Z" - hmm, doesn't make much sense

Comment: @J.R. A palindrome poem called “[Doppelgänger](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/216-poetry-lyrics-and-essays/61045377)” by James A. Lindon is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 7):

That is called a *[palindrome](https://google.com/search?q=define:palindrome)*; as the Google dictionary defines it:

> A word, phrase, or sequence that reads the same backwards as forwards

Comment: At first you mixed it up with pantomime, as the link still showed it :-)

Comment: @Impair Ah didn't realize it thanks for pointing it out.